# Remove visual studio 2010 totally

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, ide

I struggle to uninstall VS 2010. I downloaded and used first trial version for VS professionnal 2010. I uninstalled it (partially) after trial, but as I could not install and use new trial version for same product, I successfully installed VS express C++ 2010. Now trial period for this product is over as well, and I unintalled it. Now I am stuck: I can  download neither VS 2010 nor VS Express 2010. How to entirely remove VS from computer (Windows 7). Thanks and regards.

Comment: Can't you just wait for the garbage collector to remove it?

Comment: +1 for Kerrek, should be more really.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is not so much removing it, but a miss-understanding of how the express versions work.

VC++ 2010 Express is 100% free, you do however, need to [register it](http://arthy303.wordpress.com/2010/10/08/registering-visual-c-2010-express/) (it'll only allow 30 days of unregistered use), but this is free as well. if you are a student, you may consider getting the professional or ultimate versions for free off of Dreamspark or the MS Academic Alliance.

If you do want totally remove it, you can remove all the components from the windows programs manager, however, removing the trail period checks would result in circumvention of the EULA (ie: you'd be breaking the law).

Comment: You'd be breaking the law in any jurisdiction where such EULA clauses are enforceable.  Perhaps yes in the USA, and perhaps no, in many other countries. Most of us don't have DMCA equivalents.

Comment: So, if you decided to format your hard drive and re-install Windows, would you technically be violating the EULA and the DMCA?

Comment: @Ferruccio: if its done with the intent to circumvent paying for a license, then yeah, though its a costly way to do so :P

Comment: @WarrenP: its a line your shouldn't cross, regardless if how enforceable it is, plus when it comes to MS products, there is always a more legit way

Comment: I live in Canada.  US laws don't apply to me.  The line I don't cross is that I don't do illegal things. I also don't tell people in Norway not to break US laws, because that's just being stupid.  In Norway you follow the laws that apply there.  If you tell people in Norway not to break US laws, you're just being silly.